# desktop background image

Tags: .desktop

[image]Trying to set desktop background to a jpg file, but when I select the folder (left click on a spot where there is no icon on the desktop > select "Desktop settings" > lower left area there is "Folder:" > and next to it drop down list > click on "Other" > opens up "Select folder" file-browser window) files are grayed out. When I click "Open" it goes back to Desktop settings window and nothing is showing in Background tab. I searched the internet, and none of the answers seem to work. I have not tried yet the command line method.
This is xubuntu, 18.04, xfce.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. What folder? How are you "selecting it"? In what tool? What's in the folder? What are the permissions of the folder?

Comment: @terdon - edit done. Important additional information: I solved the problem by going into Thunar, navigating to the folder where my intended jpg file is, then left click on the file offered choice to set the image as wallpaper. In fact this is dangerous because it happened to me once that a left click on an image and an inadvertent mouse pointer motion resulted in replacing my desktop background (a.k.a. "wallpaper"). A confirmation window would be advisable. At that time I spent hours trying to restore my desktop image not knowing how it happened. Anyway, the original question stands.

Comment: What Ubuntu are you using? What desktop environment? Gnome? Unity? Something else? Why are you trying to set a folder as the background? What files are greyed out? Are they image files? Can you at least show us a screenshot?

Comment: @terdon - sorry, I don't know if it is Unity or Gnome - whatever came with the 18.04 and all of its updates. I'm not trying to set a folder as background, it is what Desktop settings asks from me. Yes, they are jpg files. How do I attach a screenshot? I already have it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you had already said you were using xfce, I missed that. See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting (at the end) for how to include images. We would also need to see the output of `ls -l /foo` where `/foo` is the folder you are trying to use. I want to see that you are indeed trying to use an image file (you never know) and that you have permissions to access that folder.

Comment: @terdon - screenshot image added - thanks for the instruction. As far as the ls -l /foo is concerned that folder has only jpg files, and as mentioned in my earlier comment I was able to set the wallpaper image with right click provided option in that particular image in thunar. Please, not that I'll be unavailable until late Wednesday. Thanks for your interest in resolving this issue.

Comment: Are those pictures located on another hard drive or were copied from another Linux system ? The fact that they're greyed out might suggest permissions problem either on files, folders, or if it's another hard drive - the filesystem

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy - don't think it has to do with permissions. I tested it by copying a particular jpg file to my desktop, checked permissions and it is rw_rw_r__ for my user name. Also, as mentioned before, this file is now the background (wallpaper) of my desktop using the right click method. The problem is that Desktop setting dialog shows grayed out jpg files, that it does not work as expected. This may really be a bug?

Comment: @Janos Potentially it could be a bug. As for permissions, the issue could be any other folder along the path, so `HOME/Folders/JIESZIK/Fenkypenik/2011`  check all of them. Find out what your desktop environment is first, do `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in terminal and let us know. Try to reproduce this on variety of other folders with images. It looks to me as you're using KDE desktop judging by the close,minimize,maximize buttons and grayish theme, and I don't have a VM with KDE to try reproducing this.

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy -  `janos@acerlinux:~/Desktop$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
XFCE
janos@acerlinux:~/Desktop$`  I don't think it has to do with permissions: I copied the same file to my home directory, checked permissions and OK, but still grayed out in folder. Some weird thing...

Comment: Possibly Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/502647/why-is-thunar-the-default-file-manager-in-xubuntu

Comment: @ Elder Geek - read your link, tried nautilus (sudo apt install nautilus) - no difference; switched session xfce/gnome - no difference. Then purged nautilus. OK, weird thing, no problem, no big deal.

Comment: Tested the same on another desktop machine, and there it worked: selecting a folder with jpg files did show pictures to chose for wallpaper. I'm still trying to figure out what's going on on my laptop. For some reason I'm on Session 4. Same problem on Ctr+Fn1 through3